# MonoTouch: is it possible to start PDFViewers from an Stream?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

would like to start the PDF-Viewers from an Stream instead of an
FileLocation ()

Is it possible (now or in the future) to feed

1. CGPDFDocument, or
2. QLPreviewItem

from an Stream-object?

Would like to get rid of the need to store the documents locally
before viewing them...

thanks,
Dilettanto

Comment: I don't know anything about monotouch but the SDK knows CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution.

First you need to create a native binding for function:
CGPDFDocumentRef CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider (
   CGDataProviderRef provider
);
You can use the btouch tool to do so.

The CGDataProvider then has constructor with byte [] array, so you can create a memory stream reader to provide the byte [] data for it.

Hope this helps.
@sichy

Comment: Just a note: this is not streamin. It loads evertything into memory. OOM with big files, but okay for smaller ones.